# java.net.SocketTimeoutException with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, socket-timeout-exception

I'm using Retrofit and OkHttp to connect to server.
in most times it works good. but is some case it fail.
some times HTTP **FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException** and some times  **java.net.SocketTimeoutException**. this error is just when I'm using home wifi to connect to server. but when I use mobile network it is good and there is no problem.
using with emulator is good. it happens just with real device. and just some times not all times.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();



    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ClientConfigs.REST_API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();


compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I avoid these errors?", the answer is "stop using the Internet". You will run into these sorts of problems *a lot* when you release your app and it gets used on all sorts of networks in all sorts of situations.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, 
happening in very very few devices that too intermittently, 
we have are already tried basic troubleshooting including app reinstallation, 
User has good internet connectivity,
other apps are in same device are not facing connectivity issues, 
The major exception we get in affected devices are "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to my.domain.com/64:ff9b::dea:c77e (port 443) from /2409:4089:bc92:b09:af24:6312:e6da:ca00 (port 44860) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)" OR "java.net.UnknownHostException..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current project I have the same issue. Probably it is problem with your network hardware/software. I have two routers. With first router my app works perfectly. Second router is located in another room. When I try to use app nearly it works good. But when I go to another room and try to make request with good signal - I receive `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` after 5 seconds (my timeout in Retrofit is 120 seconds).

Comment: Agree with you. I also have this problem on one device with Wi-Fi, but only after upgrade of an application. Turning to mobile network fixes the error.

Answer (score 1):

My guess your home wify is not stable as it seems.

OkHttpClient throws UnknownHostException when specified host cant be resolved (this happens when you have no internet for example).

For the SocketTimeout, OkHttp will throw this when request timeout is reached (For example if your servers takes more than 30 seconds to send back the result, but this also can be caused by your internet connection to the server)

Comment: i have the same issue but no luck on fixing it. Already added the timeout but didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: This answer was provided 2 years ago, and tbh its not a real solution to this issue.